# how to split two div tag in a web page?

Tags: html, css

below the html code and could anyone help me with this to get and responsive css code!

```
    <section class="left-section">   <!--Webpages left-side container!-->
    
        <div class="portfolio-nav" >
            <ul>
                <li>Sanjeet Kumar</li>
                <li>Front-End Developer</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="profile-pic">
            <img src="./image/profile pic.jpeg" alt="profile-Picture" />
        </div>
</section>      
</div>

<section id="right-section">  <!--Webpages right-side container!-->
    <div id="intro">
        <h1>Hi, My Name is Sanjeet Kumar.</h1>
        <p>Front-End React Js Developer, <br> Aspiring a DevOps Engineer!</p>
    </div> 

   <div class="social-link" >
        <button><a href="https://github.com/Kumarsanjeet1" class="social-link">GitHub</a></button>              
        <button><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sanjeet-kumar-86a418203" class="social-link">LinkedIn</a> </button>
        <button><a href="https://twitter.com/Krsanjeets" class="social-link">Twitter</a> </button>
        <button><a href="https://www.instagram.com/krsanjeets/" class="social-link">Instagram</a> </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

[I wanna to be make this type of webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeWmT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media query`:

p.s: Also, change the first section's class to an id, like the second one.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
  #left-section, #right-section{
      width:50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <section id="left-section">   <!--Webpages left-side container!-->  
    <div class="portfolio-nav" >
      <ul>
        <li>Sanjeet Kumar</li>
        <li>Front-End Developer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="profile-pic">
      <img src="./image/profile pic.jpeg" alt="profile-Picture" />
    </div>
  </section>      
  <section id="right-section">  <!--Webpages right-side container!-->
    <div id="intro">
      <h1>Hi, My Name is Sanjeet Kumar.</h1>
      <p>Front-End React Js Developer, <br> Aspiring a DevOps Engineer!</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="social-link" >
      <button><a href="https://github.com/Kumarsanjeet1" class="social-link">GitHub</a></button>              
      <button><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sanjeet-kumar-86a418203" class="social-link">LinkedIn</a> </button>
      <button><a href="https://twitter.com/Krsanjeets" class="social-link">Twitter</a> </button>
      <button><a href="https://www.instagram.com/krsanjeets/" class="social-link">Instagram</a> </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```